# Facing issue "Error Code: EPERM" while conducting a build for hawtio which includes typescript and Angular files

Tags: angularjs, typescript, build, hawtio

I am getting this issue during a build on my project. I am trying to modify the typescript and angular files in Hawtio API.
It gives the error message as **Error Code : EPERM.**

Using --force and other similar commands, goves successful build but doesnt give required output.

Below is the screenshot of the prompt.

[image: command prompt showing failure msg]

It does not specify any errors but the build fails everytime.
Can anyone suggest what should be the approach to rectify it?

Comment: have you tried with the --force flag?

Comment: Using that, the build gets successful but doesnt give required output.I need to figure out, what it is which is causing the build failure?

Comment: Probably phantomJs.. are you using a windows machine?

Comment: check this issue log..looks very similar : https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/19

Comment: Yes. Windows 64 bit OS.

Comment: Hey, Thanks Bala..A part of it helped. I can now atleast see the error line and column :)   Please add that as an answer and I will mark it Correct Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJs on windows machine usually causes this issue. [Issue log](http://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/19) related to the same.

Comment: Thanks Bala. Atleast now I can figure out the line causing error.